# Utilizando @Table Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, table

Como que faço para utilizar a anotação `@Table` do hibernate utilizando uma variável que traga o nome da tabela por exemplo `@Table(name = "dep4"+Dados.getCodEmp)`? Pois estou utilizando dessa forma mas me apresentada o seguinte erro:

```
The value for annotation attribute Table.name must be a constant expression
```

Preciso disso porque no banco de dados do sistema em questão as tabelas são geradas com a seguinte nomenclatura prefixo + o código atribuído a empresa, por exemplo `dep4+(CodEmp)`. Esse código eu pego de um arquivo de texto que fica dentro do diretório da aplicação.

Comment: Até dá pra fazer uma coisa, mas não entendi esse `"dep4"+Dados.getCodEmp`. Isso é o nome da tabela ou seria um "prefixo"? Tipo: `("dep4"+Dados.getCodEmp) +  "_nome_da_tabela"`

Comment: O **"dep4"+Dados.getCodEmp** seria o nome da minha tabela, onde o **dep4** é prefixo padrão do nome da tabela o **Dados.getCodEmp** é de onde eu pego o código da empresa para compor o nome da tabela. Por exemplo estou logado no banco com a empresa de código **01** então o nome da minha tabela seria **dep401**

Comment: Ah sim, a solução que eu tinha como sugestão era para outro propósito. Dá para gerar os nomes dinamicamente, mas não pela anotação `@Table`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1507980/4056678

Answer (score 1):

Creio que infelizmente não possa fazer isto.

`@Table` é um anotação do Java, e anotações Java não podem receber valores em tempo de *Runtime*. As anotações do Java só podem receber constantes, conforme a mensagem de erro lhe informou.

Answer (score -1):

Você deve criar um  [**Generating Database Schemas**](https://antoniogoncalves.org/2014/12/11/generating-database-schemas-with-jpa-2-1/) 
 ou  [**Interceptors**](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/interceptor/interceptor.html) para os schemado seu banco de dados.

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Persistence.generateSchema("samplePU", null);
   }
}
```

De uma olhada no links.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/151427)

Comment: O link não é uma resposta para o casso dele. Só coloquei  para ele da uma olhada ..

Comment: Não são regras minhas, são regras do StackOverflow, recomendo que leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour